# Is there a way to re-design webchat interface of microsoft bot?

Tags: css, .net, botframework, chatbot

I am trying to implement a chat bot using microsoft bot framework. I am using the default chat interface of the bot. Is there a way to redesign the default bot interface?

Comment: It depends on what code you can see and can change or if your able to apply your own style sheet

Comment: That's what I wanted to know if its possible to access the stylesheet of the default chatbot of microsoft bot messenger

Comment: I just updated my answer since now the web chat is open source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Refer to Update 11/16*

Currently there isn't a way to skin the web chat. This is a popular request though and there are few threads on BotBuilder discussing about this:

- [Styling web chat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1131)
- [Custom WebChat Control UI](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/202)

## Update 11/16

**The Web Chat sample is now open source and available in GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat so you can now do the customization that you want.**