# Botframework customize web chat control

Tags: botframework

Is there a way to customize the appearance of the Microsoft Bot Web Chat Control?
I've seen in the doc the ability to change size with the syntax

iframe style="height:480px; width:402px" src="..."

but how to change:

1) the accent color of the title bar

2) the language used in the automatic texts (like "Type your message...")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to re-design webchat interface of microsoft bot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40023585/is-there-a-way-to-re-design-webchat-interface-of-microsoft-bot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebChat control is an open source project.  You can fork it and make any changes you want.  Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).